# Masking and bitwise_and in openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, mask

So I just started learning openCV and I was learning about joining and masking images. So while doing some things practically, I came across two questions for the below code.

```
    ...
    # HSV values
    lower_bounds = numpy.array([h_min, s_min, v_min])
    upper_bounds = numpy.array([h_max, s_max, v_max])

    # Generating a mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_bounds, upper_bounds)
    # Using this to convert the image into a 3 channel image so as to
    # join it with other images below using the hstack and stack
    # **Line 1**
    th_mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    # Using bitwise_and with img as src1 and three channel mask as src2
    # **Line 2**
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, th_mask)

    horizontal_stack_1 = numpy.hstack((img, img_hsv))
    horizontal_stack_2 = numpy.hstack((th_mask, result))

    vertical_stack = numpy.vstack((horizontal_stack_1, horizontal_stack_2))
    ...
```

So my questions were:

1. Can **Line 1** in the code be considered correct to generate a three-channel image to join it with other three-channel images? If not what's the better solution?
2. What's the difference between **Line 2** and `result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)`, and if I just need to fetch out specific colors, which method seems better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend using cv2.split and cv2.merge while working with image channels. [detailed explanation](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/01/23/splitting-and-merging-channels-with-opencv/).
2. The operation will not execute if the mask[index] value is zero. [more](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.2/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=bitwise#bitwise-and)